# If JVM generates machine code, then where are the code files?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, machine-code

I read some materials about JVM and bytecode. I think it would be more efficient if JVM can translate bytecode into platform dependent machine code in the first time run, instead of interpreting them all the time.

However, I could not find such files in my project folders. There are only bin and src folders, which contain *.class bytecodes and *.java source codes.

So my questions are:

1. If Java interprets bytecode all the time, why not translate bytecode to machine code after the first run?
2. If they do generate machine code, where are the files?

Comment: Why waste time compiling code which might never be run again during the life of the JVM?

Answer (score 4):

1. Not an option since the environment can change between runs (e.g. upgrade of JVM)
2. In memory (or serialized to disk when needed)

Answer (score 1):

> If Java interprets bytecode all the time, why not translate bytecode
>   to machine code after the first run?

There are pros and cons to both ahead of time (AOT) and just in time (JIT) compilation.

The main advantage of AOT is that the compiler is generally allowed to take longer, so it can perform more sophisticated analysis and optimization. Another advantage is that the compiler doesn't have to be present at runtime on the target machine. The disadvantages are everything else.

The main advantage of JIT is that the compiler is able to make optimizations based on information known only at runtime. In fact, it is even possible to unoptimize and reoptimize code when conditions change. Furthermore, the JIT doesn't have to waste time optimizing code that is never or rarely run, unlike the AOT compiler.

Some languages are designed to favor one approach over the other. For example, C/C++ are designed for AOT, while Java is designed for JIT (though it can be compiled AOT with some restrictions). For example, Java has a heavy emphasis on virtual getters and setters, possibly for classes not loaded until runtime. But the JIT can see and inline these functions at runtime. By contrast, if you used virtual methods for every field access in C++, you'd pay a huge performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't interpret code all the time. Interpreted code is translated into byte code after some time. You can tweak this "time" using -XX:CompileThreshold= (default is 10000) or you can turn off compilation completely.
2. In memory. There's a special area in memory called "Code cache". You can see how methods a compiled into the cache and how they are evicted from the cache using  -XX:+PrintCompilation. The size of the cache is also configurable, see -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the JVM has preprocessed data but only for its own classes. Given the size of the JRE library and the fact that it usually doesn’t change, it’s a big win (you might look for files called `classes.jsa`).

However, even these files are not containing native code but only easier-to-process byte code.

The big point about code generation in Hot Spot JVMs is that they don’t compile code on a class or method basis as you seem to think. These JVMs compile code fragments spanning multiple interacting methods as the interaction is discovered during the self-profiling. These code blocks may span methods from the JRE, the extension libraries, 3rd party libraries in your class path and your application classes and hence are only valid for this specific combination.

During the compilation the information gathered about your program’s behavior will be used, e.g. code paths not taken might be elided and conditionals might be asserted to evaluate to a certain result as they did in previous evaluations. This yields to a high performance but it might happen that the JVM has to drop the code *even during the same execution* when one of the assertions does not hold anymore, e.g. the program might take a code path it didn’t before or a new class has been loaded into the JVM which extends a class whose code has been optimized as-if having no subclasses, etc.

So if optimized and compiled code might be rendered obsolete even within the same environment, it is even much likelier to be obsolete in the next execution. In the end, the JVM would have to check whether the old code is still appropriate which might turn out to be even costlier than simply gathering the new environment’s data and program behavior.